# flipping sprite image in Android game

Tags: java, android

I am making a game in Android that requires a list of sprites to running from right to left so I try to flip the image using the code below.

It slows the game speed down so much, moves fast running to the right but slows down so much running to the left.

```
          public void Draw(Canvas spriteBatch, int X, int Y, int imageIndex,int flip)
  {

    int drawY = (imageIndex / columns);
    int drawX = imageIndex - drawY * columns;


     int spriteX =  drawX * spriteWidth;
     int spriteY =  drawY * spriteHeight;

     Rect src = new Rect( spriteX, spriteY,spriteX + spriteWidth, spriteY +      spriteHeight);
     Rect dst = new Rect(X, Y, X + spriteWidth,Y + spriteHeight);

     location.X = X;
     location.Y = Y;

      if(flip == 1) 
      {
         //here image is flipped 
          spriteBatch.save();         
          spriteBatch.scale(-scaleX, scaleY, X, Y);
          spriteBatch.drawBitmap(texture2D,src,dst, paint);
          spriteBatch.restore();

          //Use simple use this to flip image canvas.scale(-1, 1)
      }
      else if(flip == 0) 
      {
       //draws sprite without flipping           
          spriteBatch.save();
          spriteBatch.scale(scaleX, scaleY, X, Y);
          spriteBatch.drawBitmap(texture2D,src,dst, paint);
          spriteBatch.restore();
      }


    this.SetFrame(imageIndex);
}
```

I can flip using matrix but I can't draw a sprite using matrix.
Is there a way to draw sprite using matrix and would it make it faster?

```
             matrix.reset();
             matrix.setTranslate(location.X, location.Y);
             matrix.setScale(-scaleX,scaleX);
             matrix.postTranslate(location.X + texture2D.getWidth(), location.Y);
```

Or is there another way that is faster?

Answer (score 0):

So I think that the matrix solution should will work perfectly the canvas object includes it's own built in matrix which if you manipulate will affect the output of all graphics after that point. So you just set the matrxi and then do the draw.

You're solution is okay but you're doing it wrong - rather do this part ONCE:
Create the left-ward facing sprite as you do at the beginning and then store it. Then EACH FRAME: Use this 'cached' copy of the inverted bitmap that you created.

A third solution (which I haven't tried but might work) is to manipulate the destination rectangle so that the left and right edges are swapped - the canvas docs say, "Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle." - I suspect that this might include negative scaling to fit the space where the right edge is smaller than the left although the docs do not explicitly say so.